# Update function returns errors and does not update the data

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

have not been able to make this code work the error code is (not all parameters were used in SQL statement) am attaching image of MySQL  description, have spent a lot of time but more I work on it the worse it gets and also destroys other function
please do not ignore reject or blacklist me as I have no experience fo asking a good question, will learn though

```
        self.var_DEPARTMENT =StringVar()
        self.var_COURSE = StringVar()
        self.var_YEAR_ = StringVar()
        self.var_SEMESTER = StringVar()
        self.var_STUDENT_ID = StringVar()
        self.var_STUDENT_NAME = StringVar()
        self.var_DIVISION = StringVar()
        self.var_ROLL_NUMBER = StringVar()
        self.var_GENDER = StringVar()
        self.var_DOB = StringVar()
        self.var_EMAIL = StringVar()
        self.var_PHONE = StringVar()
        self.var_ADDRESS = StringVar()
        self.var_TEACHER = StringVar()
        self.var_PHOTOSAMPLE = StringVar()
```

Function

```
    def update_data(self):
        if self.var_DEPARTMENT.get() == "Select Department " or \
           self.var_STUDENT_NAME.get() == "" \
           or self.var_STUDENT_ID.get() == "":
           messagebox.showerror("Error", "All Fields Are Required", 
               parent=self.root)
        else:
            try:
                Update = messagebox.askyesno("Update",
                    "Do you want to update studtent  data")
                global con
                self.fetch_data()
                if Update > 0:
                    con = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", 
                          user="root",password="123root",
                          database="recognition") 
                    my_cursor = con.cursor()
                    my_cursor.execute(
                        "update students set  (DEPARTMENT=%s,COURSE=%s,"
                           "YEAR_=%s,SEMESTER=%s,STUDENT_NAME=%s,DIVISION=%s,"
                           "ROLL_NUMBER=%s,GENDER=%s,DOB=%s,"
                           "EMAIL=%s,PHONE=%s,ADDRESS=%s,TEACHER=%s,"
                           "PHOTOSAMPLE=%s,WHERE STUDENT_ID=%s )",
                       (self.var_COURSE.get(),
                        self.var_YEAR_.get(),
                        self.var_SEMESTER.get(),
                        self.var_STUDENT_NAME.get(),
                        self.var_DIVISION.get(),
                        self.var_ROLL_NUMBER.get(),
                        self.var_GENDER.get(),
                        self.var_DOB.get(),
                        self.var_EMAIL.get(),
                        self.var_PHONE.get(),
                        self.var_ADDRESS.get(),
                        self.var_TEACHER.get(),
                        self.var_PHOTOSAMPLE.get(),
                        self.var_radio1.get(),
                        self.var_STUDENT_ID.get()))                
                else:
                    if not Update:
                        return

                my_cursor = con.cursor()
                messagebox.showinfo("Success", "students details updated 
                 successfully", parent=self.root)
                con.commit()
                self.fetch_data()
                con.close()
            except Exception as ude:
                messagebox.showerror("--ERR--", f"The Err is{str(ude)}", 
                    parent=self.root)
```

Comment: You have a syntax error.  You  need to remove the comma just before "WHERE STUDENT_ID".  More specifically, replace the comma with a space.

Comment: The indentation in your code is abysmal.  I'm going to try to fix it.

Comment: Next time pls share the exact error messageas well, so  we do not have to guess what the error is!

Comment: You don't need to create another cursor there.  If `con` is global, why create a new connection every time?  Normally, you create a connection once in your app, and reuse that connection everywhere, no `global` required.

Comment: is your study id an `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: No, it is not auto-increment as in design there is an ID field that takes care of Student ID though the system does not permit duplicates and shouts, however, it is primary and unique

Answer (score 0):

so i had a few weeks ago, the same problem with updating. Maybe it helps you =

```
            cur_personen.execute("UPDATE person SET  vorname=%s, nachname=%s,"            # UPDATE PERSON ////////
                                 " geburtstag=%s, stadtid_fk=%s WHERE id=%s",
                                 (

                                     self.parent.optionbar.person[1].get(),
                                     self.parent.optionbar.person[2].get(),
                                     self.parent.optionbar.person[3].get(),
                                     self.parent.optionbar.person[4].get(),
                                     self.parent.optionbar.person[0].get(),
                                 ))
```

Comment: Why are you not using `%s` for `id`.

Comment: don't know... i saved my wrong code and posted it.. now here is the right one...

Comment: It worked perfectly good thank you  Joe Mo Sir has been 4 days /7 hours a day but finding no way out , Now I am on the path

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat cleaned up version of what you had.

```
    def update_data(self):
        if self.var_DEPARTMENT.get() == "Select Department " or \
            not self.var_STUDENT_NAME.get() or \
            not self.var_STUDENT_ID.get():
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "All Fields Are Required", 
                parent=self.root)
            return
        if not messagebox.askyesno("Update",
                "Do you want to update studtent  data"):
            return

        self.fetch_data()

        try:
            con = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", 
                  user="root",password="123root",
                  database="recognition") 
            my_cursor = con.cursor()
            my_cursor.execute(
                "UPDATE students SET DEPARTMENT=%s,COURSE=%s,"
                   "YEAR_=%s,SEMESTER=%s,STUDENT_NAME=%s,DIVISION=%s,"
                   "ROLL_NUMBER=%s,GENDER=%s,DOB=%s,"
                   "EMAIL=%s,PHONE=%s,ADDRESS=%s,TEACHER=%s,"
                   "PHOTOSAMPLE=%s WHERE STUDENT_ID=%s;",
               (self.var_COURSE.get(),
                self.var_YEAR_.get(),
                self.var_SEMESTER.get(),
                self.var_STUDENT_NAME.get(),
                self.var_DIVISION.get(),
                self.var_ROLL_NUMBER.get(),
                self.var_GENDER.get(),
                self.var_DOB.get(),
                self.var_EMAIL.get(),
                self.var_PHONE.get(),
                self.var_ADDRESS.get(),
                self.var_TEACHER.get(),
                self.var_PHOTOSAMPLE.get(),
                self.var_radio1.get(),
                self.var_STUDENT_ID.get()))                

            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "students details updated successfully", parent=self.root)
            con.commit()
            self.fetch_data()
            con.close()
        except Exception as ude:
            messagebox.showerror("--ERR--", f"The Err is {str(ude)}", parent=self.root)
```

Comment: Why not use `"""` instead of splitting the query strings

Comment: That's personal preference.  If you're going to print the strings for debugging, the """ method inserts extra spaces.  No technical reason to do it either way.

Comment: Should I post the entire program for the benefit of those who get stuck like me and find no solution

Comment: Sure, add a section that says "here's what worked".

Comment: I have been banned by StackOverflow see the answer post it works perfect

Comment: Tim I am banned now